# Is there an AU plugin that has a similar use to FL Studio's Stamp Tool?

Tags: scales, midi, logic-pro, vst, audio-editing

I've seen people online using the stamp tool in FL Studio to write scales. As far as I can tell, Logic Pro X does not come with this feature. Is there a plugin (has to be AU for my purposes) that simulates this feature and what is its name?

Comment: Are you looking to set notes into a certain scale? If so, there’s scale quantization, but I’m not sure if that’s what you’re referring to. I need more info on what the stamp tool does.

Answer (score 2):

There's a versatile plugin called [Scaler](https://www.pluginboutique.com/product/3-Studio-Tools/72-Utility/3933-Scaler) from Plugin Boutigue. It's available as an AU.

Also there is [InstaScale](https://waproduction.com/plugins/view/instascale) by WA Production. This is more a scale learning and composition support plugin, available as AU as well.

Another composition support plugin helping with scales is [MelodicFlow](https://feelyoursound.com/melodicflow/) by feelyoursound. This is available as VST only.